# .net core Application is run with different port with electron.net with cross platrom

Tags: node.js, .net-core, cross-platform, asp.net-core-webapi, electron.net

I've developed an application using .NET Core and Electron.NET and created a **login form**.

For **login**, I have created separate `web API` project and call the login API on login button click.

When I call API from an application, it gives an error about "Cross-Origin", so I need to register an IP Address and Port in that API but right now I am facing an issue like `.net core` application is run on the different-different port each time.

While call sign-in in API from the **window environment** it gives me below port:**8001**

[image]

[image]

While calling the same API from the **Ubuntu** it gives me port **35941**.
So now I am facing an issue like, we have the different project for web API and it allows us to call web API on the specific port but due to each time different port generated by the electron.net, we can not call the web API in CORS (cross-origin) and it throws an error.

How can I opt-out with this situation?

Comment: which solution do you want? Electron to connect to the rando port that .net core is listening on, -or- do you want configure the port in .net core?

Comment: i want configure the port in .net core ?

Answer (score 2):

Since version **5.22.14** of Electron.NET - Is it possible to define a separate port in the **electron.manifest.json** file.

**An example of the manifest file:**
https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/blob/master/ElectronNET.WebApp/electron.manifest.json

**Add the following entry here:**
"aspCoreBackendPort": 8080

Answer (score 1):

There is a static class `BridgeSettings` in Electron.NET that gives you the port settings so you can use it to set the port in the CORS settings. For example:

```
app.UseCors((builder) => builder.WithOrigins($"http://localhost:{BridgeSettings.WebPort}"));
```

Comment: Thanks,AlesD. Let me check.

Comment: @alesd , I think **API** is located at **Web Serve**r and  "**BridgeSettings.WebPort**" is 
located at **Local Server(IIS)** ,then how  "**BridgeSettings.WebPort**" accessible in **AP**I ?

Comment: This is available if the API is in the Web application that uses Electron.NET. If it is an outside API on a different server then you are right you don't have the settings available there. Then one solution is to Allow all origins `(builder) => builder.AllowAnyOrigin();` but this is not really secure so it is better to provide a custom function to check that ignores the port number for example like this `app.UseCors((builder) => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed((originUrl) => originUrl.StartsWith("http://localhost")));`

Comment: Thanks AlesD. Let me check this and I'll update you soon

Comment: @alesd , This will compromise security.anyone can call the API if they know actual parameters of API.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest solution is to set the environmental variable with a static port (`ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:3333`) defined before dotnet start up. A great node package for setting ENV variables cross platform is `cross-env` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

This may be the first of many launch settings you wish to change. You should strongly consider setting up a `launchsettings.json` file with these configurations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1#development